# How to add a value from a clicked element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm struggling to find a way to get a list of items within a filter to populate a dive once clicked.  Ideally I want to be able select each of the checkboxes which populate a div with the name of that checkbox. there is a remove option next to the item that is populated inside the div to delete it.. an example is on the below fiddle

```
<div class="selected_items">
Accessories (remove)
</div>


<ul class="facet_type_web category facet_block  clearfix">
 <li> Accessories</li>
 <li> Shirts</li>
 <li> Shoes</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fehwnrvL/

Answer (score 1):

I created a new version of your code. You can take a look at the following link: http://jsfiddle.net/fehwnrvL/4/

Here's what I have done:

In each checkbox added an id attribute like `id="selectItem"`, in order to perform the action that removes or adds the selected item into the `<div class="selected_items"></div>`

```
  .on('change', '#selectItem', function(event) {
    // on item checkbox change finds out if the item
    // is already selected amd removes it from the div
    // otherwise generates a new item
    var $this = $(this), 
        selectedItems= $(".selected_items"), 
        selectedName = $this.attr("data-name")
        duplicated = selectedItems.find('div[data-name="' + selectedName + '"]');

    if (duplicated.length > 0) {
        duplicated.remove();
    } else {
        generateItem(selectedItems, selectedName);
    }
  })
```

For the link `(<a id="removeItem" href="#">(remove)</a>)` that removes the selected item I did something simple, on `#removeItem` click the corresponding checkbox is unchecked and then removes the element from the `<div class="selected_items"></div>`

```
  .on('click', '#removeItem', function(event) {
    // on selected item click unchecks the corresponding 
    // checkbox and then removes the element from 
    // the 'selected items' div
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this), 
        selectedName = $this.parent().attr("data-name"), 
        selectedItem = $('input[type="checkbox"][data-name="' + selectedName + '"]');
    // remove selected state
    selectedItem.prop('checked', false);
    // remove item from selected items div
    $this.parent().remove();
  })
```

Then for the pre-checked items:

```
  .ready(function() {
    // on DOM ready checks for pre-checked items
    // and populates 'selected items' div
    var $this = $(this), 
        selectedItems= $(".selected_items"),
        checkedItems = $this.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    $.each(checkedItems, function(index, elem) {
      generateItem(selectedItems, $(elem).attr("data-name"));
    });
  })
```

Every event is performed on `$(document)`. Now you should take a look at the code on the JSFiddle then if you have any doubts or questions feel free to ask.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').on('click', function () {
    $( ".selected_items" ).empty();
    $(this).html().appendTo('.selected_items');
});
```